# Using Recyclerview with Volley not working in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use Volley to get data via JSON and populate the data in RecyclerView in fragment. I have tested the code with normal activity and it works, but I am finding it difficult implementing thesame thing in fragment. I can see the response in JSON format when I Log in console but it seems no data is added to the list item, thus nothing is displayed in fragment and no error in LogCat.

**explore_content.xml**

This is the xml that'l be inflated in the adapter

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imagesExplore1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/testUrl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imagesExplore1"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_challenge.xml**

This is where I put the RecyclerView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="fragments.ChallengeFragment">


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/testRecyclerView"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ExploreImagesAdapter.java**

The adapter I use

```
public class ExploreImagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExploreImagesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<ExploreImages> exploreImagesList;
RequestOptions options;

public ExploreImagesAdapter(Context context, List<ExploreImages> exploreImagesList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.exploreImagesList = exploreImagesList;
    options = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.add_photo).error(R.drawable.back_left_icon);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ExploreImagesAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.explore_content, parent, false);
    return new ExploreImagesAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

Glide.with(context).load(exploreImagesLlist.get(position).getImage_url()).apply(options).into(holder.imageView);
holder.testUrl.setText(exploreImagesList.get(position).getImage_url());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int a ;

    if(exploreImagesList != null && exploreImagesList.isEmpty()) {

        a = exploreImagesList.size();
    }
    else {

        a = 0;

    }
    return a;
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView testUrl;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagesExplore1);
        testUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.testUrl);

    }
}

public void setItems(List<ExploreImages> data) {
    exploreImagesList = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void addData (List<ExploreImages> data) {
    exploreImagesList.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

**ExploreImages.java**

A model for the data

```
ublic class ExploreImages {

private String image_id;
private String image_url;
private String photo_year;

public ExploreImages(){

}

public ExploreImages(String image_id, String image_url, String photo_year) {
    this.image_id = image_id;
    this.image_url = image_url;
    this.photo_year = photo_year;
}

public String getImage_id() {
    return image_id;
}

public String getImage_url() {
    return image_url;
}

public String getPhoto_year(){
    return  photo_year;
}


public void setImage_id(String image_id) {
    this.image_id = image_id;
}

public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
    this.image_url = image_url;
}

public void setPhoto_year(String photo_year){ this.photo_year = photo_year;}

}
```

**ExploreFragment.java**

Finally the fragment where I make the network call and set the Adapter

```
public class ExploreFragment extends Fragment {

private JsonArrayRequest request;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private List<ExploreImages> lstAnime;
private ArrayList<ExploreImages> tempList;


public ChallengeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    lstAnime = new ArrayList<>();

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore, container, false);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.testRecyclerView);

    ExploreImagesAdapter myAdapter = new ExploreImagesAdapter(getActivity(), lstAnime);


    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

   /* myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/

    jsonrequest();

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return root;
}


private void jsonrequest() {
    request = new JsonArrayRequest(EndPoints.EXPLORE_IMAGES_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            /*Log.e("Errorrr", "["+response+"]");*/
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            int i;

            for(i=0; i<response.length(); i++){
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    ExploreImages anime = new ExploreImages();
                    anime.setImage_id(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                    anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("url"));
                    anime.setPhoto_year(jsonObject.getString("photo_year"));;
                    Log.e("CHAAAA", "["+response+"]");
                    lstAnime.add(anime);
                    ExploreImagesAdapter myAdapter = new ExploreImagesAdapter(getActivity(), 
lstAnime);
                    myAdapter.setItems(lstAnime);
                }
                catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("TESTERROR", "["+response+"]");
                }

                /*ExploreImagesAdapter myAdapter = new ExploreImagesAdapter(getActivity(), lstAnime);

                myAdapter.addData(lstAnime);*/

               setRecyclerView(lstAnime);
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(request);
}


private void setRecyclerView(List<ExploreImages> lstAnime) {
    RecyclerView recyclerViewx = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.testRecyclerView);
    ExploreImagesAdapter myAdapter = new ExploreImagesAdapter(getActivity(), lstAnime);
    recyclerViewx.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    recyclerViewx.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
}
}
```

I have searched Everywhere and tried everything but no data is displayed even when the JSON is parsed in Volley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do these things

1) Set linearlayout manager after declaring recyclerview

2) Declare recyclerview and adapter class globally

3) Update adapter after parsing JSON array to arraylist

Eg

```
public class ExploreFragment extends Fragment {

private JsonArrayRequest request;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private List<ExploreImages> lstAnime;
private ArrayList<ExploreImages> tempList;
ExploreImagesAdapter myAdapter;

public ChallengeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    lstAnime = new ArrayList<>();
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore, container, false);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.testRecyclerView);
// set layout manager here
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    myAdapter = new ExploreImagesAdapter(getActivity(), lstAnime);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    jsonrequest();

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return root;
}


private void jsonrequest() {
    request = new JsonArrayRequest(EndPoints.EXPLORE_IMAGES_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            /*Log.e("Errorrr", "["+response+"]");*/
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            int i;

            for(i=0; i<response.length(); i++){
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    ExploreImages anime = new ExploreImages();
                    anime.setImage_id(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                    anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("url"));
                    anime.setPhoto_year(jsonObject.getString("photo_year"));;
                    Log.e("CHAAAA", "["+response+"]");
                    lstAnime.add(anime);

                }
                catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("TESTERROR", "["+response+"]");
                }


            }
       // update adapter here
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(request);
}



}
```

Comment: This will not work either. You're forgetting to call `myAdapter.setItems(lstAnime);`which internally calls `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Calling just `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` wont make effect because no items were added.

Comment: check the constructor of adapter and onBindView method , no need to call setItems when data is being added in arraylist initially

Comment: Ok, it would work because you pass `lstAnime` by reference and then update that reference - that's danger and error prone logic. You should always pass a copy and use diff utils to compute the differences. But, in the case presented, both solutions would work, because you'll update the same `lstAnime` reference 2 times (one inside the adapter and one outside). So the solution it's not simply calling `notifyDataSetChanged` outside. There must be something strange happening else where.

Comment: well it depends on your requirement , like if there is any functionality like adding multiple item on button click or so , then myAdapter.setItems needs to be used . as i see the code posted there is issue in showing initially , that is definitely because on wrong implementation

Answer (score 1):

you are doing several things wrong here

1. make ExploreImagesAdapter as global variable inside of fragment and use it everywhere else
2. now when you will get your data just call your adapter and add Data in it you already have function for that.

Comment: Did it and still not displaying anything.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you're always creating a new Adapter instance and you shouldn't. Keep one instance global to this Fragment and you're good to go. Then update that same instance.

Using your code:

```
private ExploreImagesAdapter myAdapter;


  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    lstAnime = new ArrayList<>();
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerViewx = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.testRecyclerView);
    myAdapter = new ExploreImagesAdapter(getActivity(), lstAnime);
    recyclerViewx.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    recyclerViewx.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    jsonrequest();
    return root;
}


private void jsonrequest() {
    request = new JsonArrayRequest(EndPoints.EXPLORE_IMAGES_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            /*Log.e("Errorrr", "["+response+"]");*/
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            int i;

            for(i=0; i<response.length(); i++){
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    ExploreImages anime = new ExploreImages();
                    anime.setImage_id(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                    anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("url"));
                    anime.setPhoto_year(jsonObject.getString("photo_year"));;
                    Log.e("CHAAAA", "["+response+"]");
                    lstAnime.add(anime);                      
                }
                catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("TESTERROR", "["+response+"]");
                }
            }
            myAdapter.setItems(lstAnime);    
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: I have done this, still not working blank item displayed. In your code, you removed the setRecyclerView(lstAnime); method. was it intentional? Tho, I have tried it with and without it, didnt work

Comment: Yes the init is inside the `onCreateView` so you don't need that method. I've updated my answer try it again. I moved `setItems` outside the for loop, I've missed that. Also, make sure your `lstAnime`isn't empty after parsing the response.

Comment: Sadly, nothing is displayed  I checked - Log.e("CHAAAA", "["+response+"]"); in LogCat. Response is displaye well in JSON. How do I check if lstAnime is empty cause I am sure it is.

Comment: Put break points in your code and run it step by step. If `Log.e("CHAAAA", "["+response+"]");` its being called then no exception is being thrown in that case. With debug you'll see which objects are created.

Comment: I put a break point at lstAnime.add(anime);. Here is a screeshot of what I got after debugging - https://snipboard.io/cgInR8.jpg

Comment: Now put a break point in the the adapter line where you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` and run debug and watch for all the values

Comment: Surely, the data are been added to the list but I still dont know why no data is loaded in the fragment. https://snipboard.io/j0AFkz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```java
RecyclerView recyclerViewx = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.testRecyclerView);
```

this line refers to the `RecyclerView` in your activity. You should use in the fragment

Comment: Which line is that??